# How to get ticker label as dates periodically on matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, ticker

I am currently trying to configure my ticker labels so it comes up with dates at intervals(say 10 dates between the start and end of my dates in my dataset(See bottom of picture)).

The top picture is what I am trying to get my tickers to look like and the middle picture is what my tickers currently look like. Here is the code I have written so far; i believe the problem is on my 5th line, where it is commented out:

```
cm=plt.get_cmap('jet')
colours= np.linspace(0.1,1,len(xval))
sc=plt.scatter(xval,yval,s=30,c=colours,cmap=cm,edgecolor='k',alpha=0.7)
cb=plt.colourbar(sc)
#cb.ax.set_yticklabels((newdf['Date']/9))
plt.plot(xval, yrval)
plt.savefig('testreg.PNG', dpi=450);plt.show(); plt.close()
```

Ps I could only post 1 picture :( sorry

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add that 'newdf' is the dataset, see bottom picture.